# User Editing Profile troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, edit

My boss' website is a RubyOnRails app. My boss asked me to create a way for users to edit their own profile (like changing password, changing email, etc.)

There was already a user creation system and authentication system.

I created the new actions for edit the profile, the view and the model.

I tried many different ways to make the editing system working, but none worked.
Sometime the process can complete (submit the form and redirect to controller's index), but nothing was edited in the values of the user.

Here is the `Error Log`:

```
Processing AccountController#edit (for MyIP at Today_Date Current_Hour) [PUT]
    Parameters: {
        "user_edit"=>{
            "city"=>"My City", 
            "country"=>"My Country", 
            "newsletter_subscription"=>"0", 
            "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
            "street"=>"My Street", 
            "last_name"=>"My Last Name", 
            "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
            "login"=>"My.Login", 
            "first_name"=>"My First Name", 
            "email"=>"myemail@mydomain.com"
        }, 
        "commit"=>"confirm_edit", 
        "action"=>"edit", 
        "_method"=>"put", 
        "authenticity_token"=>"My_Too_Long_Authenticity_Token", 
        "local"=>"fr", 
        "controller"=>"account"
    }

NoMethodError (Attempt to call private method):
    app/controllers/account_controller.rb:90:in `edit´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `pre_process´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data´
    eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachin.rb:256:in `run_machine´
    eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachin.rb:256:in `run´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `send´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command´
    thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!´
    thin (1.2.7) bin/thin:6
    /usr/local/bin/thin:19:in `load´
    /usr/local/bin/thin:19

Rendering /var/rails/MySite/releases/MyApp/public/500.html 
(500 Internal Server Error)
```

Here is part of the controller:

```
1    require "erb"
2    require 'net/http'
3    require 'net/https'
4    class AccountController < ApplicationController
5      include ERB::Util
6      layout "store"
7    
68     def edit_profile
69         @page_title = t(:account_edit_profile)
70         if logged_in?
71             if !session.nil? && session[:dump_user]
72                 @user = retrieveFromSession(:dump_user)
73             else
74                 @user = current_user
75             end
76             begin
77                 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
78                     record_not_found
79                     redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :index)
80             end
81         else
82             flash[:notice] = t(:permission_denied)
83             redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :index)
84         end
86     end
85    
86     def edit
87        @page_title = t(:account_edit_profile)
88         if logged_in?
89             if is_active_module? :symbol_private
90                 @user = User.find_by_id!(current_user.id).update(params[:user_edit])
91                 if @user.valid?
92                     session[:dump_user] = Marshal.dump(@user)
93                     redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :edit_confirm)
94                 else
95                     render :action => 'edit_profile';
96                 end
97             else
98                 flash[:notice] = t(:permission_denied)
99                 redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :profile)
100            end
101        else
102            flash[:notice] = t(:permission_denied)
103            redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :profile)
104        end
105    end
106
107    def edit_confirm
108        if logged_in?
109            begin
110                user = retrieveFromSession(:dump_user)
111                session[:dump_user] = Marshal.dump(user)
112                if is_active_module? :symbol_private
113                    finalize_edit
114                end
115                rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
116                    flash[:notice] = t :something_went_wrong
117                    redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :profile)
118            end
119        else
120            flash[:notice] = t(:permission_denied)
121            redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :index)
122        end
123    end
124
125    def finalize_edit
126        user=(!user.nil?) ? user : retrieveFromSession(:dump_user)
127        user.save!
128            flash[:notice] = t(:profil_successfully_edited)
129            session[:dump_user]=nil
130            redirect_to(:controller=>:account, :action => :profile)
131    end
132
133 end
```

Here is the view for "edit_profile":

```
1    <div id="title_store">
2        <%= t(:account_edit_profile)%>
3    </div>
4    <div id="paragraph_store">
5        <div>
6            <%
7                labelled_form_for :user_edit, @user, :url =>{:action =>"edit"},
8                :html=>{:multipart=>true, :method=>:put} do |@form|
9            %>
10               <% field_set_tag t(:edit_profile) do %>
11                   <%= @form.text_field :login, :value=>(@user.login), :disabled=>"disabled"%>
12                   <%= @form.text_field :email, :value=>(@user.email) %>
13                   <%= @form.password_field :password %>
14                   <%= @form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
15                   <%= @form.text_field :first_name, :value=>(@user.first_name) %>
16                   <%= @form.text_field :last_name, :value=>(@user.last_name) %>
17                   <%= @form.text_field :street, :value=>(@user.street) %>
18                   <%= @form.text_field :city, :value=>(@user.city) %>
19                   <%= @form.text_field :country, :value=>(@user.country) %>
20                   <%= @form.check_box :newsletter_subscription, :checked => params[:newsletter_subscription]%>
21                   <div id="envoie">
22                       <div id="retour">
23                           <%= link_to t(:cancel), :controller=>:account, :action=>:profile %>
24                       </div>
25                       <div class="submit">
26                           <%= submit_tag t(:confirm_edit) %>
27                       </div>
28                   </div>
29               <%end%>
30           <%end%>
31       </div>
32   </div>
```

The view is inside of a layout, where there is html / head / body and the other items required for rendering the view.

I have not posted the helper, because it is unused.

Concerning the model, I didn't make it, and I do not understand it.  I only understand the part where there is the values that are required for send the form, and save it.

Here is the model:

```
1     require 'digest/sha1'
2     require 'shared/element'
3     require 'exceptions'
4     require 'rubygems'
5     require 'net/ldap'
6
7     class UserEdit < ActiveRecord::Base
8         has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
9         belongs_to :abonnement 
10        belongs_to :secretariat
11        has_many :news
12        has_many :items
13        has_many :absences
14        has_many :opener, :foreign_key => "opened_by_id", :class_name =>'Task'
15        has_many :closer, :foreign_key => "closed_by_id",:class_name =>'Task'
16        has_many :attributor, :foreign_key => "attributed_to_id",:class_name =>'Task'
17        has_many :static_pages
18        
19        attr_accessible :login,:password,:password_confirmation, :email,:is_ldap_user, :secretariat_id, :newsletter_subscription
20        attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :street, :city, :country
21        
22        validates_presence_of        :first_name
23        validates_presence_of        :last_name
24        validates_presence_of        :street
25        validates_presence_of        :city
26        validates_presence_of        :country
27      
28        validates_presence_of     :password,                   :if => :password_changed?
29        validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_changed?
30        validates_length_of       :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_changed?
31        validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => :password_changed?
32        validates_length_of       :login,    :within => 3..20
33        validates_length_of       :email,    :maximum => 50
34        validates_uniqueness_of   :login, :case_sensitive => false
35        validates_uniqueness_of   :email, :case_sensitive => false, :if => Proc.new{|u| configatron.email_uniqueness}
36        validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
37
38      
39        before_save :encrypt_password, :fix_is_ldap_user_attribute
40        before_destroy :check_godness
41        
42        extend Element
43        
44        def self.authenticate(login, password)
45            u = find_by_login(login)
46            if !u
47                raise WrongLoginPassword
48            end
49            
50            if(is_active_module?:ldap)
51                unless u.authenticated?(password) || is_in_ldap?(login,password)
52                    raise LDAPOnlyUser
53                end
54            else
55                raise WrongLoginPassword unless !u.nil? && u.authenticated?(password)
56            end
57            
58            if !u.activated_at
59                raise InactiveAccount
60            elsif u.roles.find_by_title('banned')
61                raise BannedAccount
62            else
63                return u
64            end  
65        end
66        
67        def self.encrypt(password, salt)
68            Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{salt}--#{password}--")
69        end
70        
71        def encrypt(password)
72            self.class.encrypt(password, salt)
73        end
74        
75        def authenticated?(password)
76            crypted_password == encrypt(password)
77        end
78        
79        def remember_token?
80            remember_token_expires_at && Time.now.utc  remember_token_expires_at 
81        end
82        
83        def remember_me
84            self.remember_token_expires_at = 2.weeks.from_now.utc
85            self.remember_token            = encrypt("#{email}--#{remember_token_expires_at}")
86            save(false)
87        end
88        
89        def forget_me
90            self.remember_token_expires_at = nil
91            self.remember_token            = nil
92            save(false)
93        end
94        
95        def self.content_columns
96            @content_columns = super.delete_if do |value| 
97                (value.human_name.downcase == "crypted password") ||
98                (value.human_name.downcase == "salt") ||
99                (value.human_name.downcase =~ /.*token.*/) ||
100               (value.human_name.downcase == 'password reset code') ||
101               (value.human_name.downcase == 'is ldap user') ||
102               (value.human_name.downcase == 'updated at') ||
103               (value.human_name.downcase == "activation code")
104           end
105       end
106        
107       def activate
108           @activated = true
109           self.activated_at=Time.now.utc
110           self.activation_code=nil 
111           true
112       end
113        
114       def recently_activated?
115           @activated
116       end
117        
118       def recently_lost_password?
119           @lost_password
120       end
121        
122       def password_reset?
123           @password_reset
124       end
125        
126       def is_admin?
127           (self.roles.map{ |role| role.title.downcase}.include? 'admin') || is_god?
128       end
129        
130       def is_god?
131           self.roles.map{ |role| role.title.downcase}.include? 'god'
132       end
133        
134       def is_secretary?
135           self.roles.map{ |role| role.title.downcase}.include? 'secretary'
136       end
137        
138       def make_password_reset_code
139           @lost_password = true
140           self.password_reset_code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join)
141       end
142        
143       def reset_password
144           self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join).slice(0,8)
145           self.password_confirmation = self.password
146           self.password_reset_code = nil
147           @password_reset = self.password
148           self.save!    
149       end
150        
151       def available_roles
152           if (self.roles.map{ |role| role.title.downcase}.include? 'god')
153               Role.find(:all)
154           else
155               Role.find(:all,
156                   :conditions=>["title != ?",'god'])
157           end
158       end
159       
160       protected
161       
162       def encrypt_password
163           return if password.blank?
164           self.salt = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{Time.now.to_s}--#{login}--") if new_record?
165           self.crypted_password = encrypt(password)
166       end
167        
168       def password_required?
169           if( is_active_module?(:ldap) &&  is_ldap_user == true )
170               return false
171           else
172               (crypted_password.blank? || !password.blank?)
173           end
174       end
175        
176       def make_activation_code
177           self.activation_code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join )
178       end
179        
180       private
181       def check_godness
182           raise UnautorizedDeletion if is_god?
183       end
184        
185       def is_valid_secretariat?
186           return true unless is_active_module? :ipmc
187           return true if self.secretariat_id.nil?
188           if Secretariat.find_by_id(self.secretariat_id).nil?
189               errors.add :secretariat_id, :invalid
190               false
191           else
192               true
193           end
194       end
195        
196       def fix_is_ldap_user_attribute
197           self.is_ldap_user = true if is_ldap_user.nil? && is_active_module?(:ldap)
198       end
199       
200       def self.is_in_ldap?(login ,password)
201           ldap = Net::LDAP.new
202           ldap.host = configatron.ldap.host
203           ldap.port = configatron.ldap.port
204           ldap.encryption :simple_tls if configatron.ldap.encryption
205           ldap.auth configatron.ldap.base_dn, configatron.ldap.password
206           begin
207               result = ldap.bind_as(
208                               :base => configatron.ldap.base_dn,
209                               :filter=>"(uid=#{login})",
210                               :password => password
211               )
212               rescue SystemExit
213                   return false
214           end
215           if result 
216               return true
217           else
218               return false
219           end
220       end
221        
222   end
```

I'm totally lost and I don't understand what is wrong.  don't understand 90% of the model, and didn't find anything that could help me on the web.

If someone see my error, or know how to fix the problem, or have better simple way to allow users to edit their own profile, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to make my edit system working.

My error was in trying to use a system I didn't unterstand 100%.

And at last I simple made that.

In the Controller:

```
    def edit_profile
        if logged_in?
            @page_title = t(:account_edit_profile)
            @user = current_user
            if request.post?
                if @user.update_attributes(params[:user_edit])
                    flash[:notice] = t(:profil_succesfully_edited)
                    redirect_to :controller => :account, :action => :profile
                end
            end
        else
            flash[:notice] = t(:must_logged_in)
            redirect_to :controller => :index
        end
    end
```

In the View I called a `_form.rhml` with `<%= render :partial => "form"%>`.
And in this form I wrote that:

```
<%= error_messages_for :user_edit %>
<% form_for :user_edit, @user, :html=>{:multipart=>true, :method=>:post} do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:login) %>
        <%= f.text_field :login %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:email) %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:first_name) %>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:last_name) %>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:street) %>
        <%= f.text_field :street %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:city) %>
        <%= f.text_field :city %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label t(:country) %>
        <%= f.text_field :country %>
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox">
        <%= f.check_box :newsletter_subscription, :checked => params[:newsletter_subscription] %>
        <%= f.label t(:newsletter_subscription) %>
    </p>
    <div id="envoie">
        <div id="retour">
            <%= link_to t(:cancel), :controller=>:account, :action=>:profile %>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <%= f.submit t(:confirm_edit) %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for your answers.

And I hope this post will help otherrs with the same problem than I.

Answer (score 0):

First weird thing I see is that in your controller you use User model and model which code you've posted has name UserEdit.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's the model called by the form from the view.

I already made that for registration controller and it work fine. Because the form is for modifying / creating Users, and they are from another controller.

But all of them are wrote in the same Table into the database sql.
The table "users".

Answer (score 0):

Second weird thing is in your form where you have: `do |@form|`
That should *not* be an @-variable. just use: `do |f|`

Also, you shouldn't need to be explicitly passing in the value eg `:value=>(@user.login),` - you have already specified that the form is "for" the @user, and the form should automatically pick up on those values by itself. Try simplifying all that down a bit and see if that helps (it will at least help readability).

Then, on the line that is causing the backtrace error. try splitting it into two lines to see which operation is actually causing the error eg:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
@user.update(params[:user_edit])
```

However... really, if you're just looking for the User object that is the same as the current_user... why not just use the current user and skip the find? After all, if you have current_user, then you don't need to reload the user object.

So I'd recommend replacing that line entirely with:

```
@user = current_user
@user.update(params[:user_edit])
```

Comment: the reason I used :vallue=>(@user.login) is cause I want to have the current_user informations on the form. (maybe the column login is not a good idea to edit, but it's at first for changing the email column.)

And I tryied your last line, but for unkown reason after sending the form (this time I didn't get the 500 Internal Error) the informations of the user wasn't change.

That's why I used so many diferents variables.

I'll try to split my value in two line, and I'll tell you what happens.

Comment: So I tryied to split in two line.

I still get the 500 internal error.
The "attempt to call a private method" is for the line where I wrote "@user.update(params[:user_edit])"

Comment: I tryied to remove the lines. And now, the logs tell me "undefinied method valid? for nil::NilClass"

Does it mean the variable "@user" is not send by the form to the action "edit" ?

Comment: No - your form does not automatically set `@user`. You were before setting it with `@user = current_user`. If you remove that line, then there will be no `@user` at all.

Comment: Now that you know it's the `update` line that is broken... you can test a little deeper. Lets see if current_user is actually returning what you think it is returning.  Just after the line `@user = current_user` add a line: `puts @user.inspect` - then go visit the page, and then go look at the logs to see what the puts printed out.